# Proving a random variable is chi-squared distributed

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution, chi-squared

I'm trying to work on the following problem:

Given n=8 random variables $(X_1, ..., X_8)$ where $X_i$ ~ $U(0,1)$.

Let $Y=ln(\frac{1}{X_{1}\cdot\ldots\cdot X_{8}})$

Prove that $P(Y\leq3)=F_V(6)$ where $V$~$\chi^2(16)$.

This is what I tried:

$P(Y\leq3)=P(ln(\frac{1}{X_{1}\cdot\ldots\cdot X_{8}})\leq3)=P((\frac{1}{X_{1}\cdot\ldots\cdot X_{8}})\leq e^3)=P(e^{-3} \leq X_1*...*X_8)=1-P\left(e^{-3}\geq X_{1}\cdot\ldots\cdot X_{8}\right)$

Also we know that $\chi^2(n)\equiv\Gamma(n/2,1/2)$, so using $F_{X}\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
1-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\left(\lambda\cdot x\right)^{k}\cdot e^{-\lambda\cdot x}}{k} & x>0\\
0 & else
\end{cases}$

We get that $F_{V}\left(t\right)=1-\sum_{k=0}^{7}\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot t\right)^{k}\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2}\cdot t}}{k}$

so $F_{V}\left(6\right)=1-\sum_{k=0}^{8}\frac{3^{k}\cdot e^{-3}}{k}$

But I couldn't understand why both terms are equal?

$\sum_{k=0}^{8}\frac{3^{k}\cdot e^{-3}}{k}=P\left(e^{-3}\geq X_{1}\cdot\ldots\cdot X_{8}\right)$

Comment: I am not sure exactly what your question is.  $\log_e \frac{1}{X_i} = -\log_e X_i$ has an exponential distribution with rate $1$ and thus $2\log_e \frac{1}{X_i}$ has a chi-squared distribution with $2$ degrees of freedom, so $Y=\log_e\frac{1}{\prod X_i}= \sum\log_e \frac{1}{X_i}$ has a gamma or Erlang distribution with rate $1$ and shape $8$, and $V=2Y$ has a chi-squared distribution with $16$  degrees of freedom.

Comment: You have $\mathbb P(Y \le 3) $ $= \mathbb P(2Y \le 6) $ $=  \mathbb P(V \le 6) $ $=F_V(6) $; you also have  $\mathbb P(Y \le 3)= \mathbb P(e^{-Y} \ge e^{-3})$ and from the Erlang distribution $\mathbb P(Y \le 3)= 1- \sum\limits_{k=0}^7 \frac1{k!}e^{-3}3^k \approx 0.0119$.

Comment: @Henry that was super helpful! as soon as you realize that $-log_{e}X_{i}$ has an exponential distribution with rate 1, the rest was easier! thanks :)